# Find price changes over time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with these columns: id, sku, price, date

```
CREATE TABLE price_log (
  id int NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
  sku text NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  price real NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT date_sku UNIQUE (sku,date)
)
```

I want to get a report of change price in overtime.

My desired output is:

```
sku     old_price    new_price    change_date
A          10           11         2022-01-03
B          1            5.99       2022-01-02
B          5.99         3.5        2022-01-03
B          3.5          12         2022-01-04
```

Right now the best I could do is to use `LAG()` function:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT sku, price, MAX(date) AS date
 FROM price_log
 GROUP BY sku, price
)
SELECT sku, price, date,
LAG(price,1) OVER (
    PARTITION BY sku
    ORDER BY date
) AS old_price
FROM cte
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=de5a38d3dca5fabfd5b0d2349cd8edad)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for answering. I have already added my desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are N ways to do that. For example one would be to use lateral:

```
select p1.sku, t.old_price, p1.price as new_price, p1.date as change_Date
from price_log p1, 
lateral (select price from price_log p2 
         where p1.sku = p2.sku and
               p1.date > p2.date
         order by date desc
         limit 1) t(old_price);
```

[DbFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eef78cc8725f9d0d147e76313e4eab4e)

Answer (score 2):

```
select sku
      ,old_price
      ,new_price
      ,change_date
from   (
       select sku
             ,lag(price) over(partition by sku order by date) as old_price
             ,price                                           as new_price
             ,date                                            as change_date
       from   price_log
       )      price_log
where  old_price <> new_price
```

| sku | old_price | new_price | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 11 | 2022-01-03 |
| B | 1 | 5.99 | 2022-01-02 |
| B | 5.99 | 3.5 | 2022-01-03 |
| B | 3.5 | 12 | 2022-01-04 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=af80fd4b94f5716efd225e21f6ecd16b)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT sku, price, date,
         LAG(price,1,price) OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY date) AS old_price
  FROM price_log
)
SELECT sku, old_price, price AS new_price, date AS change_date 
FROM CTE 
WHERE price <> old_price
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=25f92f3b0a03736bf3fbfb4a8bdee27a).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I couldn't accept 2 answers, sorry

Comment: It's OK, but the selected answer is not giving the expected output, or am I missing something? [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=01d9cf4cd778ecdf997df85118357c4b)

Comment: I think he updated the question because the new link is different. 
 https://dbfiddle.uk/n0hPqJSW

Comment: @MjEbrahimzadeh, still the same, is this the expected output you want https://dbfiddle.uk/k4nYAjSF

Comment: No I don't want not changed like row 1, only changed ones

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, the query is not working as you want.